# Android NFC Activity onResume onNewIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I developed a NFC Tag reader/writer by making some changes on [this example](http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/).

I have "type X" and "type Y" cards. Type X cards are Ndef read/writeable, one is Mifare Classic, one is Mifare Ultralight. Type Y cards are Ndef Formatable, one of them is protected(bus card), and the other one is not.

I get three sounds from the device (Galaxy S3), one of them is the "beautiful-sound", saying "It's easy to write and read from this card, allright". The other one is the "good-sound", saying "This card is tough, but I got some information for you.". The last one is the "ugly-sound", saying "I see you're showing me an NFC Tag, but I don't care."

When I got the application on the screen and running, I got beautiful-sound with Type X cards, can read/write and I got good-sound with Type Y cards and I can at least get their tech info.

However, When I got the application running on background and I'm at the main menu of the device, I got beautiful sound with Type X cards and everything works great and when I tap Type Y cards I get ugly-sound and the app doesn't show up on the screen, nothing happens.

Below you can see parts of my code, I think I'm doing something wrong with **onResume** or **onNewIntent** operations. Any idea what can be wrong according to the code, or is there anything else that might cause this kind of thing? Thanks 
My onStart:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.write_tag).setOnClickListener(mTagWriter);
    mNote = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.note));
    mTechNotes = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tech_notes));
    mNote.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

    // Handle all of our received NFC intents in this activity.
    mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    // Intent filters for reading a note from a tag or exchanging over p2p.
    IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        ndefDetected.addDataType("text/plain");
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) { }
    mNdefExchangeFilters = new IntentFilter[] { ndefDetected, tagDetected };

    // Intent filters for writing to a tag

    mWriteTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
}
```

My onResume:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mResumed = true;
    // Sticky notes received from Android
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        NdefMessage[] messages = getNdefMessages(getIntent());
        byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        setNoteBody(new String(payload));
        setTechNotesBody(getTagInfo(getIntent()))
        setIntent(new Intent()); // Consume this intent.
    } else if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        setTechNotesBody(getTagInfo(getIntent()));
        setIntent(new Intent());
    }
    enableNdefExchangeMode();
}
```

My onPause:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mResumed = false;
    mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundNdefPush(this);
}
```

My onNewIntent:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // NDEF exchange mode
    if (!mWriteMode && NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        NdefMessage[] msgs = getNdefMessages(intent);
        promptForContent(msgs[0], getTagInfo(intent));
    } else if(!mWriteMode && NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        promptForContent(null, getTagInfo(intent));
    }

    // Tag writing mode
    if (mWriteMode && NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        writeTag(getNoteAsNdef(), detectedTag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've not got a filter in the manifest then your application won't be launched to handle the tag.